# Прання в множині

Tags: правопис

Як правильно? 
Одяг не втрачає свій вигляд після численного прання.
Або
Одяг не втрачає свій вигляд після численних прань.

Answer (score 2):

Українська граматика 2019 року

> УЖИВАННЯ М’ЯКОГО ЗНАКА (Ь)
>
> § 26. Коли пишемо Ь. Буквою ь позначаємо на письмі м’якість
>   приголосних звуків.
>
> 1. Ь пишемо:
>
>    2) у родовому відмінку множини іменників жіночого роду м’якої групи
>      першої відміни на -я: гри́вень, друка́рень, їда́лень, пісе́нь,
>      ста́єнь; крамни́ць, ма́триць, робітни́ць та **середнього роду другої
>      відміни на -нн-**(я), -ц-(е): бажа́нь, знань, кі́лець, місць, серде́ць і
>      серць, але бур, зір, Мотр (після р);

[**Прання**](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) - **іменник**, **середній рід**, **2 відміна**, **м'яка група**. Тобто пишемо **прань**.

Comment: Те, що Ви пишете (що в родовому відмінку множини такі сліва мають м'який знак) безумовно правильно. Але мені здається, основне запитання: чи має тут бути тут форма множини (як у «із численних кілець» — р.в. мн.) чи _прання_ слід розглядати як збірне поняття (як у «із численного студентства» — р.в. одн.). І тут справді має бути множина, бо тут під _пранням_ мається на увазі дія (слово _прання_ може бути й збірним, але в значенні «речі, які перуть», а не в значенні дії).